# Cordova battery status event only fires on first page

Tags: android, events, cordova, battery

I have written a small app in Cordova with the battery plugin (tried versions 0.2.11 to 0.2.13-dev). The html contains a href to a second page. The deviceready event is fired on the first and on the second page and the battery status eventlistener is added on both pages. But on the second page the battery status event is not fired anymore, when i go back to the first page, it is not fired anymore, too.

I tried on Android 4.1 and Android 4.4 devices.

It seems that the battery status event fires only on the initial page.

Does anyone have experienced the same? Is there eventually a solution or workaround for this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

I expect this event is only fired once the application is started - meaning the Cordova Javascript parts are loaded and in cache. I expect the Cordova Javascript from cache is used even when loading a second html page.

You may want to use the Javascript `window.onload = function ...` to execute something when the page has been loaded.